# How to add padding before CheckBox/RadioButton across API levels

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I want to add padding to the left/start of `RadioButton` and `CheckBox` views. The motivation for this is to have full width selectable lists (for select one and select multiple) where the radio button or check box element have space between themselves and the screen edge but also don't end up with a non clickable area where that space is.

For API 16 and below I can add the spacing AND maintain clickability I can use the view's `paddingLeft` attribute. For API 17 and above this attribute controls the padding between the button/box element and it's corresponding text (which of course we also want to control).

For API 21 and above I can use a drawable inset like so to create the desired layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_standard"
    android:button="@drawable/inset_radio_button"
    tools:text="Option A">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:insetLeft="@dimen/margin_standard" />
```

This however appears to end up offsetting click feedback (the ripple). So a few questions:

1. Is there a better way to create this spacing across all (16 and up really) API levels?
2. If no hope for 1), is there a better way of creating this spacing for API 21 and above that doesn't mess with the ripple feedback?
3. If there is no hope for 1) or 2) what is the most **creative** solution to this? For example, a view to the left of these views that propogates touch events to them or a container with padding that does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that we could create the spacing across API levels using a combination of `drawableStart`, `drawableLeft`, `buttonCompat` and `drawablePadding` to hide the `button` and explicitly set the drawable:

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_standard"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_standard"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_standard"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_standard"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:drawableStart="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:button="@null"
    app:buttonCompat="@null"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_standard">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton>
```